# Not getting previous item in app which associated with parse.com

Tags: android, xml, parse-platform

In my application it is app for quiz and i have added code for getting next question it is working fine but when i am coding for getting previous question then it is giving wrong question .

```
public class GamePlay {
    private int numRounds;
    private int right=0;
    private int wrong=0;
    private int round=0;
    private List<ParseObject> question = new ArrayList<>();
    private List<Question> questions = new ArrayList<Question>();
    public int getRight() {
        return right;
    }
    public void setRight(int right) {
        this.right = right;
    }
    public int getWrong() {
        return wrong;
    }
    public void setWrong(int wrong) {
        this.wrong = wrong;
    }
    public int getRound() {
        return round;
    }
    public void setRound(int round) {
        this.round = round;
    }
    public void setQuestions(List<Question> questions) {
        this.questions = questions;
    }
    public List<Question> getQuestions() {
        return questions;
    }

    public Question getNextQuestion(){
        //get the question
        Question next = questions.get(this.getRound());
        //update the round number to the next round
        this.setRound(this.getRound()+1);
        return next;
    }


    public Question getPrevQuestion(){
        //get the question
        Question next = questions.get(this.getRound());
    //  Question nextp = questions.get(this.getRound()-2);
        //update the round number to the next round
        this.setRound(this.getRound()-1);
    //  this.setRound(this.getRound()-2);

        return next;
    }




    public void incrementRightAnswers(){
        right ++;
    }
    public void incrementWrongAnswers(){
        wrong ++;
    }
    public void setNumRounds(int numRounds) {
        this.numRounds = numRounds;
    }
    public int getNumRounds() {
        return numRounds;
    }

    public boolean isGameOver(){
        return (getRound() >= getNumRounds());
    }


    public void setQuestion(List<ParseObject> question) {
        this.question = question;
    }

    /*public void setprevQuestion(List<ParseObject> question) {
        this.question = question;
    }
*/
}
```

and calling section of previous question is here :-

```
public class QuestionActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

    private Question currentQ,prevQ;
    private GamePlay currentGame;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_question);
        /**
         * Configure current game and get question
         */
        currentGame = ((ParseApplication)getApplication()).getCurrentGameAccen();
        currentQ = currentGame.getNextQuestion();

prevBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                prevQ = currentGame.getPrevQuestion();
currentQ=prevQ;
                setQuestions();
            }
        });
private void setQuestions() {
        //set the question text from current question
        String question = currentQ.getQuestion() + "?";
        TextView qText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.question);
        qText.setText(question);

        //set the available options
        TextView option1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.answer1);
        option1.setText( currentQ.getOptionOne() );

        TextView option2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.answer2);
        option2.setText( currentQ.getOptionTwo() );

        TextView option3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.answer3);
        option3.setText( currentQ.getOptionThree() );

        TextView option4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.answer4);
        option4.setText( currentQ.getOptionFour() );
    }


    @Override public void onClick(View v) {

        //validate a checkbox has been selected
        if (!checkAnswer()) return;

        // check if end of game
        if (currentGame.isGameOver()){
            Intent i = new Intent(this,EndgameActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
            finish();
        } else {
            Intent i = new Intent(this, QuestionActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
            finish();
        }
    }


    @Override public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        switch (keyCode) {
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK : return true;
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }


    /**
     * Check if a checkbox has been selected, and if it
     * has then check if its correct and update gamescore
     */
    private boolean checkAnswer() {
        RadioGroup options = (RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.group1);
        Integer selected = options.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
        RadioButton checkedbut= (RadioButton) options.findViewById(selected);

        int corrss=currentQ.getCorrectAnswer();
        RadioButton corransofparse= (RadioButton) options.getChildAt(corrss - 1);
        int idofparseans=corransofparse.getId();
        //Log.d("answithcorrect", corrss + "uiyguigkj" + idofparseans+""+corransofparse);

        if ( selected < 0){
            return false;
        } else {
            if (idofparseans == selected ) {
                currentGame.incrementRightAnswers();
            } else {
                currentGame.incrementWrongAnswers();
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Now next button click is giving exact next questin but previous button is not giving proper result .

Comment: What result are you getting when you select the previous question?

Comment: so if i am getting 10 elements from parse then on click of next button it is working fine.but when i click on previous button then i can not immediatly go back to previous question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok , So actually what happens in your code is that your app is downloading questions from parse.com from there collections and storing it in mobile db directly by parse methods , Now what i am suggesting is that , you correct your way by :-

1>> code of downloading question from parse is right .
2>> Now just make same db in sqlite or suger framework at mobile db .
3>>Then save your question and options with answer in that mobile db in one time running 
4>>Now use code algorithm is like :

```
if(mobiledb.getAllquestion()!=null)
{
///
Question arr[]=mobiledb.getAllquestion();
//Now you do code for next and previous button click but transaction must be //from arr[] array .
}
else
{
//code to download question from parse.com and then save them at mobile db.
}
```

Hope it will help